# activity crashes when switching fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a activity with a listview and a button, when the button is clicked i add in a fragment. My problem is that when i scroll in the fragment then close the fragment the listview in the activity is also scrolled also when i click the button to bring the fragment back the app crashes. Any help?

main activity code

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
 ListView listView ;
 Button B;
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
 FragmentManager fragmentManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

     // Defined Array values to show in ListView
      String[] values = new String[] { "1", 
                                      "2",
                                      "3",
                                      "4", 
                                      "5", 
                                      "6", 
                                      "7", 
                                      "8",
                                      "9",
                                      "10",
                                      "11",
                                      "12",
                                      "13",
                                      "14",
                                      "15",
                                      "16",
                                      "17",
                                      "18",
                                      "19",
                                      "20",
                                      "21",
                                      "22",
                                      "23"



                                     };
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


           // Assign adapter to ListView
           listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    B=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B.setOnClickListener(this);
}

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch(v.getId())
    {
         case R.id.button1:
             Second s = new Second();

             fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, s);

              fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
             fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Cam");
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
         break;





    }


   }

   }
```

Comment: Please add the crash logs

Comment: Show your stacktrace.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.example.fragmenttransisition, PID: 8193
       java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
  at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:583)
 at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575)
 at com.example.fragmenttransisition.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the following:

```
 switch(v.getId())
    {
         case R.id.button1:
             Second s = new Second();
             //add this
             fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();  
             fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, s);
             fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
         break;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the crashing issue, but how do i stop the listview in the main activity from being scrolled?

Comment: sorry i didn't quite get you there. Why do you need to stop the listview from being scrolled?

Comment: when i click the button the fragment opens and covers the screen with its view, however is i scroll in the fragment and close the fragment the listview is also scrolled

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

Remove first `fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();` from `onCreate(...){...}` method

and place this code on that case, i.e.,

```
    @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch(v.getId())
    {
         case R.id.button1:
             Second s = new Second();
             fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
             fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, s);

              fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
             fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Cam");
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
         break;
    }

   }
```